# Nuget Local Repository Missing Nuget Package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I created a local nuget repository in order for offline computers to access the packages.

I set my local repo and I can see all packages except for one.  This package is preventing my solution from building.

I have tried Restoring the package and installing the package with the source argument to the local package.  Neither works.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Local Repo**
[image: Local Repository]

**Dll exists in the Nuget Package**
[image: Dll exists in the Nuget Package]

**Nuget Browser**
[image: Nuget Browser]

**Nuget Packages Installed For This Solution**
[image: Nuget Packages Installed For This Solution]

**Force Install Error**
[image: Force Install Error]

Answer (score 0):

The source parameter you are passing does not look correct to me. Also you do not show which package source you have selected in the Package Manager Console.

You are passing in a filename when it should be the name of the package source.

Or you can simply just select that package source in the Package Manager Console and not use the source parameter when running Install-Package.

Comment: I tried Install-Package AutoMapper with the Package Source as the Local Repo.  New error is "Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution.  The package need to be restored in order to build the dependency graph.  Restore the packages before performing any operations."    Unfortunately it fails on restoring packages.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error when you restore? Both from the UI or from the command line? Just wondering if AutoMapper NuGet package is not the one that the restore is failing to find.

Comment: Error occurred while trying to restore package.  Could not find AutoMapper

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. The Browse tab in your screenshot does not show AutoMapper for some reason so NuGet cannot find it to install but the Installed tab shows it as installed. Might be worth reporting this at https://github.com/nuget/home/issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help Matt.  I'm not sure either.  Might be some meta data issue with AutoMapper and my local repo.  I just pulled the dll out and referenced it :(